# ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved update_attributes unexplainable error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, update-attributes

With Rails 3.2 I am receiving an ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved and cannot see why. The only thing that occurs to me is some kind of gem conflict, but other than that, this error defies all Rails conventions and documentation as far as I can tell.

Any help will be highly appreciated as my sanity is quickly being put in jeopardy.

The ActiveRecord class

```
=begin
  create_table "decks", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "deck_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "core_deck_id"
    t.datetime "published"
    t.datetime "deleted_at"
    t.boolean  "customizable"
    t.integer  "deck_group_id"
    t.boolean  "has_sections"
    t.string   "solid_filename_mac"
    t.string   "solid_filename_pc"
  end 
=end

class Deck < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name

end
```

and I am receiving the following error:

```
1.9.3p433 :001 > @deck = Deck.find 6850
  Deck Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `decks`.* FROM `decks` WHERE `decks`.`id` = 6850 LIMIT 1
 => #<Deck id: 6850, name: "____lizztest2", deck_type: "core", created_at: "2013-04-15 14:57:38", updated_at: "2013-04-15 18:43:04", user_id: nil, core_deck_id: nil, published: "2013-04-15 18:43:04", deleted_at: nil, customizable: true, deck_group_id: nil, has_sections: false, solid_filename_mac: nil, solid_filename_pc: nil> 
1.9.3p433 :002 > @deck.update_attributes!({name: 'new_name'})
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:104:in `save!'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `block in save!'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:264:in `save!'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:228:in `block in update_attributes!'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:226:in `update_attributes!'
  from (irb):2
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from /Users/bliff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@pss/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3p433 :003 >
```

And here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'mysql2'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'yui-compressor'
end

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'daemons' # for delayed_job
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'meta_search'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'paranoia'
gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'query_trace'
gem 'rdoc'
gem 'will_paginate'

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'paperclip-matchers'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda'
end
```

Comment: Who were you, DenverCoder9? What did you see?!